# Electron.JS is being very CPU intensive, I can't tell what's wrong with my code

Tags: node.js, electron

I have written an application to show GPU/CPU/RAM loads in electron.js! It was all ok until I started implementing gauges to graphically display temperatures. This section is shown below, I have also included a screenshot of task manager showing hundreds of command and powershell windows!

```
 function getGPUtempHome(){
     let stinker = si.graphics();
     stinker.then(function(tempGPU){
         GPUtempHome = tempGPU.controllers[0].temperatureGpu;
         console.log(GPUtempHome);
         document.getElementById("GPUtemps").innerHTML = GPUtempHome+'°';
         document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--GPUTEMP', GPUtempHome*1.8 + 'deg');
     });
     setInterval( function() {getGPUtempHome();}, 5000 );
 }

 function getRAMhome(){
     let stinker3 = si.mem();
     stinker3.then(function(RAM){
         RAMUSAGE = Math.round(((RAM.used/RAM.total)*100));
         console.log(RAMUSAGE);
         document.getElementById("RAMloads").innerHTML = RAMUSAGE+'%';
         document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--RAMLOAD', RAMUSAGE*1.8 + 'deg');
     });
     setInterval( function() {getRAMhome();}, 5000 );
 }
```

The code above fetches RAM load or GPU temperature every 5 seconds, it then updates a HTML/CSS gauge.

If writing a program like this is unviable in electron.js are there any other better options out there, I am open to playing around with new languages/libraries.

Comment: Start deleting code systematically until the problem goes away. You'll quickly find out what part causes the issue. If you have memory/performance problems with your code, porting your code to something else doesn't make those magically disappear.

Comment: Tip: As it's 2021, consider using JavaScript template strings, like `\`${GPUtempHome}°\``.

Comment: Tip: If you're just passing a function wrapped in another function, just pass the function. That is `setInterval(function() { x() }, N)` is the same as `setInterval(x, N)` except way more verbose.

Comment: You're continually adding more and more intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) sets a *recurring timer*, so your code is basically saying "Every five seconds create *another* timer for every five seconds." After ten seconds you will have 2 timers. After 20 you now have 8. After 60 seconds you have 4,096 of them. Every 5 seconds the number of timers doubles.

That sounds like a problem, doesn't it?

What you want to do is set *one* timer, *once*, per function:

```js
function getRAMhome(){
    let stinker3 = si.mem();
    stinker3.then(function(RAM){

        RAMUSAGE = Math.round(((RAM.used/RAM.total)*100));
        console.log(RAMUSAGE);
        document.getElementById("RAMloads").innerHTML = RAMUSAGE+'%';
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--RAMLOAD', RAMUSAGE*1.8 + 'deg');
    });
}

// Set timer outside of the function
setInterval(getRAMhome, 5000);
```

It's a common problem to confuse `setInterval()` which sets a repeating timer with [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) which sets a one-shot timer that needs to be re-engaged. You're treating the former like the latter, with disastrous consequences.

Comment: It is unless your computer has infinite memory and CPU resources, in which case you might not even notice it happening.